# Java- Numerical method for integrating normal distribution?

Tags: java, helper, normal-distribution

Code:
(Yes, I'm aware its inefficient and generally quite bad. Just wonderint why it doesnt work.) Maths may be wrong, but most likely the coding is. Any help would be nice.

```
public class NormalDistribution {

static void normalDistributionDecode(double u, double sd, double x) {
    double z = ((x-u)/sd);
    System.out.println("The point "+x+" on a normal distribution "
     +"with standard deviation "+sd+" and mean "+u+" translates"
     +" to point "+z+" on a normal distribution with mean 0 and"
     +" standard distribution 1");
}

static void standardNDAlgorithm(double x) {

    double pi    = 3.1415926535;
    double e     = 2.7182818284;
    double fx    = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(x , 2))))/(2*pi);
    long end     = -10;
    double fend  = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(end , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double a = x-0.25;
    double b = x-0.75;
    double c = x-1.0;
    double d = x-1.25;
    double E = x-1.5;
    double f = x-1.75;
    double g = x-2.2;
    double h = x-2.25;
    double i = x-2.5;
    double j = x-2.75;
    double k = x-3.0;
    double l = x-3.25;
    double m = x-3.5;
    double n = x-3.75;
    double o = x-4.0;
    double p = x-4.25;
    double q = x-4.5;
    double r = x-4.75;
    double s = x-5.0;
    double t = x-5.25;
    double u = x-5.5;
    double v = x-5.75;
    double w = x-6.0;
    double y = x-6.25;
    double z = x-6.5;
    double cw= 0.25;
    double f1 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(a , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f2 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(b , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f3 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(c , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f4 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(d , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f5 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(E , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f6 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(f , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f7 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(g , 2))))/(2*pi);       
    double f8 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(h , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f9 = (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(i , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f10= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(j , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f11= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(k , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f12= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(l , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f13= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(m , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f14= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(n , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f15= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(o , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f16= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(p , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f17= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(q , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f18= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(r , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f19= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(s , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f20= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(t , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f21= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(u , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f22= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(v , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f23= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(w , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f24= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(y , 2))))/(2*pi);
    double f25= (Math.pow(e, (-0.5*Math.pow(z , 2))))/(2*pi);       
    double integfx= 0.5*cw*(fend+fx+2*(f1+f2+f3+f4+f5+f6+f7+f8+f9+f10
              +f11+f12+f13+f14+f15+f16+f17+f18+f19+f20+f21+f22+f23+f24+f25));
    System.out.println(integfx);
    System.out.println(fx);
    System.out.println(f1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
normalDistributionDecode(0, 1, 10);
standardNDAlgorithm(10);
}
}
```

ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore ignore

Comment: what is going on here? where does ignore come into the equation? what is your problem?

Comment: Maybe if you start by using arrays to represent your data (instead of a b c etc...), your code will be cleaner and more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to compute an approximation to an integral of a probability density function via Simpson's rule. There are different ways to do it, but that's an acceptable approach.

I see some problems with the formulas you are using to compute the density at each point.

(1) denominator should be `sd * sqrt(2 * pi)`.

(2) each point a, b, c, etc should be something like `(n.nn - u)/sd` where n.nn is 0.25, 0.75, etc.

There may be other problems.